# Traefik SSL without let's encrypt

Tags: ssl, traefik

Is there a way to use to use traefik (with docker swarm) and SSL without 'let's encrypt'.

Let's encrypt support is awesome (https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/docker-and-lets-encrypt)  but I don't need letsencrypt as we run our own CA in our org.

Is there a way to simply put certificates (.crt and .key) somewhere as we don't need to generate them  (in a folder or as secrets). Do you have any idea how to do that ?

We would like to do a very basic setup and have a few containers in the swarm cluster, and we want to target them by domain, ex: https://foo.ourdomain.com   and https://bar.ourdomain.com

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a volume for traefik:

```
  - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/acme/yourcrt.crt:/yourcrt.crt
  - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik/acme/yourcrt.key:/yourcrt.key
```

in your docker-compose and refer to it in traffic.toml:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
   [entryPoints.http.redirect]
     entryPoint = "https"
   [entryPoints.https]
     address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      certFile = "/yourcrt.crt"
      keyFile = "/yourcrt.key"
```